# Using IF LARGE when there is text in column

Tags: excel

I have an excel column of numbers and texts. I tried to use "IF LARGE" to find top 3 numbers of the column (A1 to A7), and return "Yes" to the cells right next to the top 3 (in column B). But unfortunately, the cells next to the texts also returned "Yes". This is the data:

```
0.2         
0.3     Yes
0.5     Yes
0.1
0.8     Yes
asdf    Yes
jklm    Yes
```

This is the code for cell B7:

```
=IF(A7>=LARGE($A$1:$A$7,3),"Yes","")
```

Any suggestions to fix this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(N(A7)>=LARGE($A$1:$A$7,3),"Yes","")
```

Comment: Awesome. Never seen `N` used that way before. Thanks!

Comment: When I change 3 into 50, all the cells in column B return "#NUM!" because there is only five numbers in the column. In this case, is it possible to make that five numbers return "Yes" and that two texts return blank, instead of "#NUM!" at the cells?

Comment: Not sure I understand. So you're saying that you want to check whether an entry is in the top 50 largest values in that range, and if there are in fact only x largest entries in the range (where x<50), then instead to check whether the entry is in the top x largest values?

Comment: I mean, let's say I don't know there is only 5 numbers in that column, and I try to find top 50 values of that column, then return the values to the column B (as before). And because there is only 5 numbers in column A, all the 5 numbers return to column B.

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like, for A1: =IF(N(A1)>=LARGE($A$1:$A$100,MIN(50,COUNT($A$1:$A$100))),"Yes","")

Comment: Yes, that's it. It works perfectly. Thanks again XOR LX. You're great

Comment: `N()` is not the right solution if the array contains any zero or negative numbers.

Comment: @AnotherParker: you are right. The texts return zero so it doesn't work well when I have zero or negative numbers, because the texts become larger than the numbers. Any suggestion to change N( )?

Comment: I think this is right:        =IF(AND(N(A1),N(A1)>=LARGE($A$1:$A$100,MIN(50,COUNT($A$1:$A$100)))),"Yes","")

Comment: @AnotherParker Good spot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A7),IF(A7>=LARGE($A$1:$A$7,3),"Yes",""),"")
```